# Adding Dynamic XML to a data source in SSRS

Tags: xml, vb.net, reporting-services

I need to get an XML response from our API and query it in SSRS. In my custom code, using System.Net.Webclient, I query our API and get the result. Here is by VB code.

```
Public Function getXML() As String

    Dim client = New System.Net.WebClient()

    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "MY TOKEN HERE")

    client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/xml")
    Dim RestURL = "MY_URL_HERE"
    Dim text = client.DownloadString(RestURL)
Return text
End Function
```

As you can see this returns a string. I add a data source and set it to this XML string but that does not work. I tried creating an XElement and XDocument object and passing it along but that does not work either. I get an Error during processing of the ConnectString expression Any help would be appreciated.

I know for a fact that my code returns an XML string. I checked by adding to to a text box.

Comment: See if this msdn tutorial helps : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I just fed the string directly into SQL server and queried it there

```
declare @myDoc xml  


set @myDoc =@xmlString --fed to a parameter first and then into the query


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://<custom namespace here>')
SELECT  x.v.value('name[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as name,
        x.v.value('date[1]', 'date') as date,
        x.v.value('ID[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as ID,
        x.v.value('Title[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as Title

FROM    @myDoc.nodes('/root/xyz') x(v)
```